# How to replace NA in a matrix with Random numbers using R?

Tags: matrix, random, replace, numbers

I have many matrices with different proportion of NA.

That I need is to replace the NA with unique RANDOM numbers of ten digits that start with 2013 (e.g 2013956737, 2013956567, etc.).

To solve that it is important that the random generated number are not repeated.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

I got it with the flowing code

```
mat[is.na(mat)] <- sample(2013900000: 2013990000, size=sum(is.na(mat)), replace=F)
```

where mat is my matrix of data